# ASP function not returning mssql insert id

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, recordset

Having a strange issue with a mssql insert and trying to retrieve the insert id trough a function call. The strange thing is the last insert id is fetched and I can print it out in the function but it returns an empty value via the function if I structure my sql statement in the following way:

```vbs
function sqlInsert(table, byVal fieldList)

    sqlInsert = 0 ' default in case of error
    .... ' removed code that builds sql for simplicity
    sql  = "insert into " & table & " (" & insertFields & ") values (" & insertValues & ")"
    sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON;" & sql & "; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS NewID"

    set rs = oCn.Execute(sql)

    response.write rs("NewID") ' 28 for example

    sqlInsert = rs("NewID") ' empty!! 
end function
```

The function works and executes the insert statement correctly and rs("NewID") **does** contain the correct inserted row id. However, nothing is returned to the function call. eg:

```vbs
result = sqlInsert("tablename", data)
response.write result 'empty!!
```

If I seperate the sql as follows:

```vbs
sql  = "insert into " & table & " (" & insertFields & ") values (" & insertValues & ")"
set rs = oCn.Execute(sql)
set rs2 = oCn.Execute("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS NewID")
response.write rs2("NewID") '28 for example
sqlInsert = rs2("NewID") '28
```

....then that works and the result of the function call contains the insert ID.

```vbs
result = sqlInsert("tablename", data)
response.write result '28
```

in both cases, the recordset contains the correct insert id in the "NewID" but only second method returns the id to the function call. Why? I have tried `cInt(rs("NewID"))` in the first example but still nothing.

I know I could just use the second method but the first is one less call to the database and I just want to know why it doesn't return the value when clearly the value is present in the rs value if I write it out before assigning it to sqlInsert.

Comment: My advice is to avoid using string concatenation for generating sql. It represents a security risk (sql injection)

Comment: All the input is cleansed in the process of building the statement but point taken.

Comment: Are you actually returning the value, e.g. `return sqlInsert`?

Comment: This is classic ASP - the value is returned in the function name

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the function to the actual Field object, which gets invalid when you're getting out of the scope it was declared in.

This should work fine:

```
sqlInsert = CStr(rs("NewID").Value)
```

And also close the recordset afterwards and Set to Nothing.

Comment: No, still doesn't return the value - if I write it out inside the function it works so I know it is returning the insert id.

Comment: @ws8 another idea: try adding `Set rs2=rs2.NextRecordset` in the function. Any change?

Comment: Sorry not sure if I get it. Rs2 is not defined in the first example but if I try this with rs I get - Object doesn't support this property or method: 'rs.NextRecordset'. In the second example, the id is returned by the function so this step is not needed.

Comment: Keep in mind that rs("NewID") does contain the record id. It's just not getting passed back by the function.

Comment: Let's try to debug. Instead of this: `response.write result` have such line: `response.write("type: " & TypeName(result))`. What you see as the output now?

Comment: type 14 - that's just for typename on rs("NewID") - I have tried to change the result to int but still didn't anything in the function name.

Comment: thanks for the help so far, I have decided to use  ado recordsets and written a class to handle all my SQL queries and updates. I am still keen to understand why this issue happened but I am thinking it may just be a bug in IIS as I have come across another similar issue that works fine in production but not in my dev server running the IIS on a windows 8. The second issue also relates to getting data from a recordset which comes up blank with direct assignment, eg foo = rs("bar), yet works fine if I convert the recordset to a dictionary object. Strange indeed...

Comment: @ws8 yep baffled as well here. So you got it all working now with the new code?